# Syntax error when assigning column value using CASE WHEN in Computed Column Formula

Tags: sql-server, calculated-columns, case-when

I'm trying to use the following CASE WHEN in computed column alias, but it shows syntax error.

```
[Password_Last_Changed] [datetime] AS
SELECT CASE
WHEN ([SUA_History1_Date] IS NOT NULL) then [SUA_History1_Date]
WHEN ([SUA_History1_Date] IS NULL) then [SUA_History2_Date]
WHEN ([SUA_History2_Date] IS NULL) then [SUA_History3_Date] 
WHEN ([SUA_History3_Date] IS NULL) then [SUA_History4_Date] 
WHEN ([SUA_History4_Date] IS NULL) then [SUA_History5_Date]
ELSE NULL 
END
```

Not sure what went wrong. If there is a better approach for this logic, please let me try it.

Comment: Remove SELECT keyword. Also, CASE is "weird".

Comment: Last 3 `When` will never execute

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using [COALESCE](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190349.aspx) is better option than ISNULL or CASE..WHEN for this problem since the input values for the `COALESCE` expression can be evaluated multiple times.

You can also use [NULLIF](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177562.aspx) to check the conditions in those `NULL` valued columns.

A NULL value for `ISNULL` is converted to `int` datatype whereas for `COALESCE`, you must provide a data type. `ISNULL` takes only 2 parameters whereas `COALESCE` takes a variable number of parameters.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [COALESCE](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190349.aspx):

```
COALESCE([SUA_History1_Date],[SUA_History2_Date],[SUA_History3_Date],[SUA_History4_Date],[SUA_History5_Date])
```

> Evaluates the arguments in order and returns the current value of the first expression that initially does not evaluate to NULL.